# Private node module pull inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, ssh

I have a private repository of a node_module which I install by including it in package.json

```
ssh://git@github.com/iamsaquib/<pivate-repo>.git
```

When I am copying all server files inside docker image and try to do a npm install it is unable to install the package and throws I don't have proper access rights. I think I have to authorize by copying my id_rsa.pub inside Dockerfile and add it as authorized key, what is the correct way to do this?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12-slim

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /app
USER root

COPY . .

RUN ./install.sh
RUN ./build.sh

EXPOSE 8000 

CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

Comment: mount local ssh keys `-v ~/.ssh:/home/node/.ssh`, maybe `~/.gitconfig:/home/node/.gitconfig` too

Comment: I saw somewhere it said to add id_rsa a.k.a the private key that is not the right way right? Also I do need to add id_rsa.pub to authorized keys?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount SSH private key (`/home/yourname/.ssh/id_rsa`).

You should avoid putting private key in Docker images. One work around could be [multi-stage image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) (security might still be debatable).

```
FROM node:12-slim as installer
ENV NODE_ENV=development
WORKDIR /app
USER root
COPY /home/yourname/.ssh /home/root/.ssh
COPY /home/yourname/.gitconfig /home/root/.gitconfig
COPY . .
RUN ./install.sh
RUN ./build.sh
RUN rm -rf /home/root/.ssh
RUN rm -rf /home/root/.gitconfig

# Final image
FROM node:12-slim
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=development
USER root
COPY --from=installer /app .
EXPOSE 8000 
CMD ["./run.sh"]
```